# How to enable migrations through code only without using Package manager console

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework Code first in my application. But while using this after updating model, every time I have to enable automatic migrations and run `update-database` using package manager console. Does anyone has solution on this, whether we can automate this and `update-database` without using package manager console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to run `Enable-Migrations` once, to generate the `Configuration.cs` class and the `Initial` migration. After that, whenever you change the model you have to generate a new migration by running `Add-Migration`, and also you have to run `Update-Database` to apply the migration to your database, but you shouldn't need to run `Enable-Migrations` again.

If you want to automate the process you can enable the automatic generation of migrations by setting `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true` in the constructor of your `Configuration` class, and use the  `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` database initializer in your `DbContext`. This would allow you to just change your model code and not having to do anything with Package Manager Console, no `Add-Migration` nor `Update-Database` required. You still need to run `Enable-Migrations` once, at the beginning, after you create the project, to generate the `Initial` migration.

Anyway automatic migrations can cause some problems, I wouldn't really recommend you to use them. So I would keep on doing the manual `Add-Migration` commands whenever your model changes. You can still skip doing the `Update-Database` if you use the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` database initializer.

Another way to do it would be using a `DbMigrator` to run the equivalent to `Update-Database` from your code (but you don't need to do this if you are using the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` database initializer):

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new DbMigrationsConfiguration());
migrator.Update();
```